# Restoring a backup database (.bak file) - Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to restore a backup file from Miscrosoft - Integration Services in order to accomplhish their tutorial. ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package?view=sql-server-2017 ). However, when i try to restore their db to my SQL Server Management Studio, it gives me an error saying that the 'Specified cast is not valid'.

Can someone help me in order to be able to complete the tutorial?

Here are the steps i've done in order to restore de db: 
[image]

And here is the error i get when i click OK:

[image]

Every help is apreciated, if extra info is necessary, i'll gladly provide more.

Thanks!

Comment: Can copy back up somewhere else (not being on desktop or root drive) and try again?

Comment: I've tried in the Microsoft SQL Server folder aswell. The output is the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to restore 2012 version DB in SQL Server 2008 R2.  Please check your SQL Server version and download appropriate database.  This could be the reason.

Comment: This was my fear :| 
So, in order to accomplish this, i must download the SQL Server 2012 and then restore it there?

Comment: Yes, that will be the right approach. Other option you can download 2008 R2 version of Adventureworks DBs from https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks2008r2

Comment: Glad to help you. Good Luck.